# Could <hgroup> be used for markup in order to make a container for heading and subheading?

Tags: html, css, markup, heading

Example ...

**HTML:**

```
    <hgroup>
      <h1>I'm a Title!</h1>
      <p class="sh1">It's a subtitle there! :D</p>
    </hgroup>
```

**CSS:** *There I set the styles for headings and subheadings. Note that html5 doesn't support subheadings, so I had the following idea with classes..*

```
    h1 { font-size: 2em; } /* default */
    h2 { font-size: 1.5em; } /* default */
    h3 { font-size: 1.17em; } /* default */ /* default for h4 is .83em; */

    :root {
        --sh1: 1.75em; /* subheading text size for h1. */
        --sh2: 1.335em; /* subheading text size for h2. */
        --sh3: 1em; /* subheading for text size h3. */
    }

    p .sh1 { font-size: var(--sh1); } /* shn means subheading */
    p .sh2 { font-size: var(--sh2); } /* it would work like <hn> tag */
    p .sh3 { font-size: var(--sh3); } /* it would be great to have <shn> */
```

So, my question is ...

As you may know, w3c actually doesn't support `hgroup` tags, because they were irrelevant. They used to contain several hn headings, and that was considered a bad idea and didn't pass through the w3c recommendation system.

Therefore, my idea is ...

Instead of being a simple container for several hn headings, it would be nice to use `hgroup` tags to enclose each `hn` headings alongside `shn` subheadings right inside that same hgroup! =D

Edit:
**This is not about asking the w3c to change how the hgroup works, is about asking you if my idea is markup-reliable and respects the w3c system**
*My bad*

Comment: This question seems to be about how to organise a social movement to petition for change; that - despite the subject of that desired change - does not make this a programming question. Incidentally, don't add your 'tags' to your signature; we have question tags already. Duplicating them as text within the question provides no help to anyone and obscures the question you're (trying) to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, but seems instead to be a question about how a group of people could be motivated to petition for change.

Comment: what is it about the `<header>`tag ??

Comment: @G-Cyr I was using `<h2>` for subheadings of the `<h1>` headings, and then I realised that was a bad habit. So I had the idea of creating the classes `.sh1` for `<p>` elements, meaning subheader for `<h1>`.

Then I asked a petition for w3c but I didn't mean this post is about making a social movement to petition for change, I meant if it was correct to use my idea and if it did respect markup syntax logic.

Comment: @David Thomas the point on including the tags inside the question's last line is because the `hgroup` and `subheading` tags did not exist. And I did need to have at least 1500 reputation points to create a new tag. By the way, I won't insert the tags into the question once ever again, but I still think that it should be not forbidden.

Comment: I was  asking about `<header>`, because it is a typical use for it

Comment: @G-Cyr ah, no. I talk about headings (`h1`), not `header` tags hehe

Comment: `hgroup` is still [partially implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup) (see "Usage Notes") in most browsers, so repurposing it on your own initiative is probably not a great idea.  Meanwhile your use of `<p>` tags as subheads is *clearly* semantically incorrect; use real header tags, or at least include an ARIA heading role.

Comment: also, since an `hgroup` has not sematic relevance, why not just use a `div` instead? What **extra** does using an `hgroup` get you?

Comment: I didn't mean to repurposing it on my own initiative, that is why I ask the question, because I didn't knew if I was being semantically correct or not.

Then that answers my question, thanks @Daniel Beck and Paulie_D ;) I will try out using divs and ARIA.

Comment: By the way, which element should I use to identify the subheading? `<p>`? <`span`>? thanks for your attention.

Comment: `h1` through `h6` tags are for headings. `p` is for paragraphs, `span` is for inline elements.  The names of the tags are pretty self-explanatory about their purpose.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: That's actually only true in the living spec. W3C HTML5(.2) [*does* forbid the use of h1-h6 and require the use of p to mark up subtitles due to its omission of the hgroup element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements), and it's been this way ever since the HTMLWG dropped hgroup from their spec a number of years ago. This then boils down to whether the author wants to follow WHATWG HTML or W3C HTML5.

Comment: I learned something new today. Thanks @BoltClock

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BoltClock =) you just could fix my dilema finally xD

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is part of how the `hgroup` element was defined to work in previous W3C HTML5 drafts, and how it still is in the current [WHATWG living spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element). (In fact, your markup conforms fully to WHATWG HTML.)

Except `hgroup` is no longer in W3C HTML5, and hasn't been for a few years with seemingly no plans of being reinstated. If you want to follow W3C HTML5, you simply aren't allowed to use `hgroup` at all.